# JQuery tabs in JSP

Tags: jquery, jsp

I am having difficulties finding a basic example of using jquery with jsp in NetBeans. Anyone have a resource bookmarked?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

JSP is just a server side view technology which provides a template to write plain HTML/CSS/Javascript in and enables interaction with the "back-end" Java code in flavor of taglibs (with [JSTL](http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/) as well known example) and [EL](http://java.sun.com/j2ee/1.4/docs/tutorial/doc/JSPIntro7.html) (Expression Language).

jQuery is "just" a Javascript library. You can just handle it as you usually do with Javascript. Every tutorial which you find about jQuery can perfectly be applied on a JSP page. If you actually have a hard understanding in what JSP is and how to let it "interact" with Javascript/jQuery, then you may find [this article](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/05/javajspjsf-and-javascript.html) useful to get started.